# How do I terminate a OneLogin session from an RP?

Tags: single-sign-on, aws-amplify, serverless, onelogin

I have a React SPA where I originally used Cognito to authenticate users to access secured Lambda microservices.  Now I have to integrate SSO with a SAML based, back-office, vertical app.

I added connectors to OneLogin for the vertical app, added OneLogin as an Idp for Cognito and added an OIDC connector for my SPA and changed the SPA to authenticate with OneLogin instead of Cognito.  SSO is working correctly but my users cannot sign out.  When they sign out of either the SPA or vertical app and return, it signs them on again.  If they navigate to the vertical app, they are signed on there too. Postman tells me that I still have access to the AWS gateway endpoints as well.

According to the Developer KB at OneLogin, [https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/users/log-user-out], no logout endpoints or functions are available but I can use the V1 api.  The docs are so outdated, I don't know if I can trust them.

As of November this thread [https://github.com/onelogin/onelogin-oidc-node/issues/8] said the logout function would be available Q1-2021 but I can't find any docs on new functionality.

I tried to use the v1 API to logout as recommended but I receive a CORS error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://api.us.onelogin.com/api/1/users/***/logout' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
VM95:1 PUT https://api.us.onelogin.com/api/1/users/***/logout net::ERR_FAILED
```

Failing code:

```
  const putOptions = {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: { 
      'Authorization' : 'bearer:' + token,
      'mode' : 'no-cors'
    }
  };
  const response = await fetch(`https://api.us.onelogin.com/api/1/users/${userid}/logout`, putOptions);
```

If I understand correctly, I think I have to establish an API "session" first using a client_secret and client_id before calling the APIs.  This is a serverless app using only microservices.  I can't embed the secret and id in JS.

How do I terminate the OneLogin session across all three connectors from an RP without a server and without disclosing the client_id and client_secret?

Answer (score 0):

I knew I was over thinking it.  I found the v2 logout endpoint at [https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/api/logout].